# VScode Run Build Task (a .bat file), with absolute path on other drive. See the command terminal output, no infinite loop. Windows 10

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, batch-file, task

Alright, I've seen similar stuff to the question I'm asking on stackoverflow, on different thread, but none of them actually works, just nothing happens. The commands I used works on the fresh command prompt in a single line.

What I want to do: Be able to run build task (CTRL SHIFT B) to execute a batch file, which has the build script. I' working on windows right now.

By default, VSCODE Terminal is CD'ed into "C:/Users/Username".
My Batch file is on the E: Drive, the name countain spaces.

Here is the build task that I setup:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build the game",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cmd",
            "args": [
                "/e",
                "E:\\School and Work\\University (real)\\Semester 7\\C++ Project\\build.bat"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I did test and all it does it create an infinite loop. It never runs. The content of build.bat is simply

```
echo This has runned.
```

So it's not an error on that end.

and it loops infnitely. The task is always running. Nothing happen, the first line of the script never gets executed.

I tried a different batch file that creates a directory, to see if it's just the output that's dead, but that didn't run either.

I usually had a batch file with the g++ command to build my program. It worked from the terminal and Windows GUI, again, didn't work from vscode.

It just never activates the first line and somehow gets stuck in an infinite loop.

[image: In case infinite loop on run task wasn't clear, here's a picture.]

I tried many different syntax for running it and it just didn't work.

However, if in the task.json, i used a simple Echo command, it works.
If I try to simply run a bat file inside the default directory C:/User/Username/

it works.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Why is this working?????",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "something.bat",
            "group": {
                "kind": "none",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Anyway, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You should be using either `/D` & `/C` or `/D` & `/K` as options for `cmd.exe`, not `/e`, _(which only enables extensions, and those are enabled by default anyhow)_.

Comment: If `shell` is specified, the command is interpreted as a shell command for the default shell (in Windows usually cmd.exe, or powershell.exe. As a batch file uses cmd.exe anyhow, there seems little need not to use `"type": "shell",` with `"command": "E:\\School and Work\\University (real)\\Semester 7\\C++ Project\\build.bat",`. However, with `"type": "process",` you should be able to use `"command": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",` and `"args": ["/D", "/K"," "E:\\School and Work\\University (real)\\Semester 7\\C++ Project\\build.bat"],`, _remembering you can replace `/K` with `/C` as needed_.

Comment: It may also be worth noting, as `.bat` and `.cmd` are by default registered Windows executable scripts, you may even be able to use `"type": "process"`, with `"command": "E:\\School and Work\\University (real)\\Semester 7\\C++ Project\\build.bat",`.